# Grant permission to a directory from command line

Tags: command-line, file-permissions, windows-server

I'm trying to grant permission to a file from the command line for the user `IIS6.0`.

So far I've tried `icacls /grant ISS_WPG:(RX,W) 'namefile'`, but with no result.

Comment: What you mean **W** here (RX, W)?

Comment: W = Write permission.
RX= Read & Execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
icacls FILE /grant USER:(RX,W)
```

The filename goes first.

Comment: thanks for the anwser,
More specific, i have error on 'USER:' list:

-If I want to grant access to a directory for 'Everyone', I have to use this syntax?

'icacls DIR_NAME /grant Everyone:(RX,W)'

Comment: Yes, although you may want to add `(CI)(OI)` to enable inheritance: `icacls DIR_NAME /grant Everyone:(CI)(OI)(RX,W)`

Comment: Well, if it is, consider [accepting](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH) it. ;)